# ActiveCell.Formula Runtime error VBA

Tags: vba, dynamic, runtime-error, excel-formula

I am trying to insert a formula to excel using VBA, but it does not work. It returns a runtime error 1004. I tried a few tricks, or answers here, but they did not seem very relevant to my case.

Here is the code:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTIFS('DataSheet_B'!$C$4:$C$13268;B6;'DataSheet_B'!$M$4:$M$13268;A6;'DataSheet_B'!$J$4:$J$13268;$G$5)"
```

In a second step, I am trying to replace `13268` in `$C$13268` by a variable that changes dynamically. I only need to insert it in the formula. That's the main reason why I am trying to hard code the formula.

Alternatively, I am using the following formula:

```
Dim sVal As String
    sVal = "13268"

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(DataSheet_B!R4C3:R[" & sVal & "]C3,RC[-5],DataSheet_B!R4C13:R[" & sVal & " ]C13,RC[-6],DataSheet_B!R4C10:R[" & sVal & " ]C10,R5C7)"
```

However, it does not return the second dollar sign of `$C$13268`

Thank you

Comment: use debugger. see what value your dynamic variable is holding at the runtime error

Comment: I am not at that step yet. I want the static formula to work first. I have tried the dynamic version with another formula but it worked fine. The piece of code above does not work.

Comment: try `ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTIFS('DataSheet_B'!$C$4:$C$13268,B6,'DataSheet_B'!$M$4:$M$13268,A6,'DataSheet_B'!$J$4:$J$13268,$G$5)"`

Comment: Perfect :/ deceitful excel. Thank you very much. Now, I will try to insert the dynamic value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all `;` *semicolons* with `,` *commas* to start off with

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTIFS('DataSheet_B'!$C$4:$C$13268,B6,'DataSheet_B'!$M$4:$M$13268,A6,'DataSh‌​eet_B'!$J$4:$J$13268,$G$5)"
```

if you want to use a variable within a string then

```
Dim sVal As Long
    sVal = 13268

ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTIFS('DataSheet_B'!$C$4:$C$" & sVal & ";B6;'DataSheet_B'!$M$4:$M$" & sVal & ";A6;'DataSheet_B'!$J$4:$J$" & sVal & ";$G$5)"
```

Comment: How about using an integer (int) instead of a long.. + int +  does not seem to work.

Comment: an `Integer` you mean? usage: `dim myInt as Integer`, be aware of [its limits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164754(v=office.10).aspx)